# sails image upload path to database

Tags: model, controller, sails.js

I am trying to upload an image using sails. I can get the image uploaded, but I want to try pass the path through my model into the db so it is part of the post and I can easily call it later.

```
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "image": [
        "rule": "string",
        "message": "Value should be a string (instead of null, which is an object)"
        "rule": "required",
        "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null\nSpecifically, it threw an error.  Details:\n undefined"
  "model": "Post",
```

Here is my model

```
image: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
},
```

And my controller

```
create: function (req, res, next) {
    Post.create( req.params.all(), function postCreated(err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      //image upload
      req.file('image').upload({
        dirname: '../../assets/images/'
      }, function(error, uploadedFiles) {
        // do something after file was uploaded...
      });
      // end upload

      res.redirect('/post/show/' + post.id);
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your question correctly. You want to upload the image in one call with create? If yes, then thats not possible in sails.
Something like below.

```
req.file(file).upload(
    {
      adapter: skipperS3Alt,
      key    : sails.config.s3Key,
      secret : sails.config.s3Secret,
      bucket : sails.config.s3Bucket
    }, function (err, files){
    return whenDone(err, files);
  });
}, function doneUploading(err, files){
  if (err){
   // error
  } else if (files[0][0] && allowedTypes.indexOf(files[0][0].fd.split('.').pop()) === -1){
    // matching file type
  }
  Model.create({
    addressProof    : files[0][0] ? sails.config.s3AmazonUrl + files[0][0].fd : ''
  }).then(function (document){
  // Do something
  })
```

Comment: I am trying to upload the image and put the image name in my database.

Comment: With the above code you will get the image name in database, "files[0][0].fd"